# Populating collection via an interface/factory?

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I am using a pattern where a concrete ViewModel implementing an interface is passed to a repository, which then populates the ViewModel object, but only using the interface.  This makes for a little heavier repository, but has allowed the repository to be reused in different scenarios.  For example, the concrete implementation could be a MVC ViewModel, or it could be asp.net Page that implements the interface, where the set accessor for each proeprty is actually putting the value in to the GUI, like a textbox for example.  The implementation of the interface serves as the mapping and eliminates an extra step of copying.  Having used AutoMapper extensively, and now being exposed to this pattern, I prefer this.

```
public interface IPerson
{
  int Id{set};
  string Name{set};
  string Address{set};
}

public class PersonRepository
{
   GetPerson(int id, IPerson person)
   {
      //query...    
      person.Id = result.Id;      
      person.Name = result.Name;
      person.Address = result.Address;    
   }
}

//...controller action
PersonViewModel person = new PersonViewModel();
rep.GetPerson(5, person);
```

Here comes the tricky part though.  Sometimes the ViewModel needs a collection of items, either for an Index page or for something like a drop down, or to display a nested set of child objects.  The repository can't instantiate an interface, so we provide it was a factory.  After fighting with covariance for awhile, I gave up on exposing any type of collection and ended up with a method that both creates and adds the collection item:

```
public interface IPerson
{
  //...
  IJobRole CreateAndAddJobRole();    
}

public class PersonViewModel:IPerson
{
  //collection not part of the interface
  ICollection<JobRoles> JobRoles {get;set;} //= new List<JobRoles> in constructor

  public CreateAndAddJobRole()
  {
    role = new JobRole();
    JobRoles.Add(role);
    return role;
  }
}

public class PersonRepository
{
   GetPerson(int id, IPerson person)
   {
      //...
      foreach(var result...)
      {
        IJobRole role = person.CreateAndAddJobRole();
        role.SomeProperty = //...
      }
   }
}
```

Obviously I'd probably have the repository that handles job roles actually be the one to populate the collection.  I'd probably actual have more granular interfaces so that different repositories would be responsible for populating the data they deal with.  The ViewModel would simply implement multiple interfaces. That to say, I realize there's room for improvement, but I am here specifically because I don't have any good ideas for dealing with the collection problem.

The one benefit of this design is there is no collection exposed which could be misused by the repository.  There is never a guess about who is responsible for instantiating the collection itself, or who populates it, or if you had just a getter, the repository could get the collection and modify it in an invalid way.  I think these would be rare occurrences because of the team would know the pattern, but it's always nice to not have pitfalls at all, instead of having pitfalls there that everyone has to remember to not step in.

As it is, it feels a little mucky.

**How would you design/expose the ability for concrete types to be instantiated and added to collection, when the method doing so only has knowledge of the interfaces?**

Comment: Is `IPerson<TJob>() where TJob : IJobRole` viable at all?

Comment: That would be possible I guess, but I'm curious where you're going with that.  Would this be so that IPerson could then have a concrete type declared for the collection, i.e. `new TJob()`? (took me a couple minutes) If so, that makes lots of sense, but maybe get messy with lots of collections on a ViewModel since that'd be something like IPerson<JobRole,ExemptionType,BenefitType...>.  Maybe that can be solved by having other repositories each responsible for their own type(e.g. IJobRole).  Gives me another option to think about.

Comment: Pretty much.  I'll flesh it out into a whole answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your best bet is to make each interface generic, and pass in the types of the collections.  For example:

```
public interface IPerson<TJob> where TJob : IJobRole
{
  ICollection<TJob> JobRoles {get;set;} 
  void AddJobRole(TJob role);
}

public JobRole : IJobRole
{
}

public class PersonViewModel:IPerson<JobRoles>
{
  //collection is now part of the interface
  ICollection<JobRoles> JobRoles //= new List<JobRoles> in constructor

  public void AddJobRole(JobRoles role)
  {
    JobRoles.Add(role);
  }
}

public class PersonRepository
{
   GetPerson(int id, IPerson<JobRoles> person)
   {
      //...
      foreach(var result...)
      {
        person.AddJobRole(new JobRole { 
            SomeProperty = //... 
            SomeOther = //...
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Of course, this assumes that you know which type of `IPerson<>` you want when you call `GetPerson()`. If you need it to handle any `IPerson` there, though, it becomes more problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this and what I and others have done in similar scenario is leverage the `new()` constraint on generic type to allow the deeper code to instantiate the concrete type requested by calling code.

```
public interface IPerson<R> where R : IJobRole, new()
{
    IList<R> JobRoles { get; set; }
}

public class JobRole : IJobRole
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public int SomeOther { get; set; }
}

public interface IJobRole
{
    string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    int SomeOther { get; set; }
}

public class PersonViewModel : IPerson<JobRole>
{
    public IList<JobRole> JobRoles { get; set; } = new List<JobRole>();
}

public class PersonRepository
{
    public P GetPerson<P,R>(int departmentId, P person) 
        where R : IJobRole, new() where P: IPerson<R>//, new()
    {
        // Optionally instead of passing in the root view model, 
        // we could also instantiate it with new P()
        // var person = new P();

        List<PersonEntity> entities = db.GetPeople(departmentId);
        foreach (PersonEntity entity in entities)
        {
            // Use new R() to create a new instance of whatever concrete type the caller asked for
            person.JobRoles.Add(new R {
                SomeProperty = entity.Some,
                SomeOther = entity.Other
            });
        }
        return person;
    }
}
```

Usage, calling code specifies desired concrete types in the generic type params:

```
PersonViewModel person = GetPerson<PersonViewModel, JobRole>(1, new PersonViewModel());
```